# QT QMainWindow fullscreen geometry without frame size

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I'm building a QT application for Windows 7, using MinGW.
In my code, I have a class derived from QMainWindow. This mainwindow is showed and closed several times (over different screens). I'm showing the window using the following code:

```
this->blockSignals(true);
this->close();
this->blockSignals(false);
this->showMaximized();
this->setGeometry(QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(mDisplayNumber));
```

Only the first time when this code is exectued, the window is showed as expected. The next times, the window is showed maximized, but i'm missing a few pixels at the bottom of the screen.

I also receive a warning in QT, when the code is executed:

**setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 1600x1172+0+0 on QWidgetWindow/'CDisplayClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  1600x1150+0+22 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 780x539, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).**

What i don't understand is that the geometry returned by desktop() >availableGeometry looks like to be incorrect. My question is, how can i determine the geometry showed in the warning message? (1600x1150+0+22)

Comment: I tried the above code with the mDisplayNumber as -1 in linux ubuntu. Executed the code in both button click & constructor. And it worked fine. Is it possible to you to give some more detail in code. (i used QT Creator 3.6.0 & Library 5.5.1)

Comment: There is not so much detail information to add. I think this is a Windows specific issue. The result of QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry() looks to be correct. The screen resolution of my screen is 1600x1200. The result of this function is 1600x**1172**, so it looks like there are 28 pixels reserved for the taskbar. But calling showMaximized() leads to the warning showed above. (I'm using Qt 5.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Center_a_Window_on_the_Screen
Now, my Show function is as follows:

```
Qt::WindowStates WindowState = this->windowState();
if(WindowState == Qt::WindowMaximized)
{
  this->setWindowState(WindowState ^ Qt::WindowMaximized);
}

this->setGeometry(
    QStyle::alignedRect(
        Qt::LeftToRight,
        Qt::AlignCenter,
        this->size(),
        QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(mDisplayNumber)));

this->showMaximized();
```

I still got a warning: setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 1600x1150+0+11 on QWidgetWindow/'CDisplayClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  1600x1150+0+22 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 780x539, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).

The resolution is the same (1600x1150) and the window is showed as expected.